# ¿Como limitar los digitos del campo año de un input date?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy haciendo un formulario utilizando `javascript`, en el formulario utilizo un input de tipo `date` y me gustaría aprender una manera de poder limitar a 4 dígitos el año del input, ya que si agrego más de 4 dígitos el año que obtengo de dicho input se altera, por así decirlo.

Por ejemplo, si la fecha es `01/04/2019`

Al hacer un `console.log()`, me devuelve: `2019-04-01`.

Pero a la hora de colocar `01/04/201952`, me devuelve: `201952-04-01` y ya la fecha no es la que deseo, si no es un error.

¿Existe alguna manera de limitar los dígitos de la fecha?

- Código:

```js
$(".formulario").change(function (){
    
    var fecha = $("#fecha").val();

    console.log('\n');
    
    console.log(fecha);

    console.log('\n');
    

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>

   <label for="fecha">Fecha</label>
   <input type="date" name="fecha" id="fecha" class="formulario">

</form>
```

Comment: No te sirve utilizar un condicional? (year >= 1500 && year < 9999), en teoria como el año es un numero, el ejemplo que diste siempre sera correcto tengo entendido =/

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera lo intente pero no funciona, ya que si coloco un año con 6 dígitos, por ejemplo, `202000` a la hora de obtener el mes y día, me afecta estos valores también, ya que obtendría 0 y el año si tomaría `2020`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se me ocurre que lo hagas del siguiente modo

- Con los atributos `min` y `max` estableces los rangos de fechas que aparecerán disponibles en el calendario para que el usuario pueda elegir
- Como el `value` de la fecha elegida es un *string* entonces podemos con `split` convertirlo a un *vector* y leer el valor del índice 0 que sería el año
- Capturamos lo que el usuario eliga del calendario en el evento `change`
- Evaluamos en un condicional si el año de la posición 0 del vector es mayor *por ejemplo a 2021* **solo como ejemplo** y en concecuencia dejamos que el valor asignado al calendario sea la leyenda de que aparece por *default*

Código

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Ejemplo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input id="fechita" type="date" min="1970-12-31" max="2022-12-31">
    <script>
      let cajaFecha = document.getElementById("fechita")
      cajaFecha.addEventListener("change", () => {
           let fecha = document.getElementById("fechita")
           let transformada = fecha.value.split("-")
           console.log(transformada[0])
          
           if(transformada[0]>= "2021") {
             fecha.value = ""
           }
      })
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: +1, muchas gracias!

Comment: @Alvarez el comportamiento de la respuesta es algo extraña, si colocas un año mayor a 2021 se elimina todo lo que hay en el input, ¿seguro que es lo que estas buscando?

Answer (score 1):

puedes intentar usando los atributos min y max para limitar a 4 digitos, por ejemplo:

```
<input type="date" name="input" min='1900-01-01' max='9999-12-31' title="Por favor ingresa una fecha entre 1900-01-01 y 9999-12-31" required/>
```